# Recursive function issue in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I need to solve this problem STRICTLY using recursion

```js
// 2. Compute the sum of an array of integers.
// sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]); // 21
```

And then I'm testing this solution in PythonLive

```js
var sum = function(array) {
  if(array.length===0){
    return array
    }
  
  return array.slice(0,array.length)+sum(array.pop())

};
sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

Then at step 6 it says "TypeError: array.slice is not a function"

I don't understand why if it already worked taking 6 off the array and returning the remaining array...

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong please?

thanks! :)

Comment: You have an array of numbers, when you recurse with `array.pop()` as the argument you're passing a number, not an array. Numbers do not have a slice method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the return values you will see that you are always returning an array. This can't be right when you want a number as a final result. When `array.length === 0` you can safely return 0 because that's the same of an empty array. That's your edge condition. After that you just want the sum of one element plus the rest.

You can also just return the array length when it's zero making for a very succinct solution. `&&` shortcircuits returning the left element if it's false (like 0) otherwise the second:

```js
var sum = (array) => array.length && array.pop() + sum(array)

console.log(sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

If you prefer `slice` you could also this, which is basically the same:

```js
var sum = (array) => array.length && array[0] + sum(array.slice(1))

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: Super CRAZY and ELEGANT solutions you Jared and Mark! Thanks! I'm a beginner now but I hope I can reach your level one day!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are processing the values the wrong way around, it should be

```
return sum(array.slice(0,array.length-1)) + array.pop();
```

In fact since `array.pop()` removes the element, you can just do it this way around:

```
return array.pop() + sum(array);
```

You also need to return `0` when `array.length===0`, otherwise the sum will fail.

```
if (array.length===0) return 0;
```

However it's much simpler just do this with `reduce`:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(arr.reduce((t, v) => { return t + v; }, 0));
```

Comment: Good recommendations, except your solution, return array.pop() + sum(array); is returning strings

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Ur right in the pop method actually! :) the problem with that its that its actually returning not a result of a sum but ANOTHER array with the same number either backwards or regular BUT all along together, not as separated elements.

I need the answer to be 21... :(

Comment: I've edited (again!) to include the fact that you must return 0 when the array is empty, not `array`

Answer (score 1):

Recursive sum function:

```
const sum = list => {
  if (!list.length) return 0;
  return list.pop() + sum(list);
};
```

Because `.pop` mutates the array, you don't need to use slice. For a non-destructive version (doesn't alter the original array):

```
const sum = ([first, ...rest]) => {
  if (first === undefined) return 0;
  return first + sum(rest);
};
```

Comment: Super CRAZY and ELEGANT solutions you Jared and Mark! Thanks! I'm a beginner now but I hope I can reach your level one day!

Thanks!

Comment: @Adolf caring about elegance is the first step on the road. Safe travels!

Answer (score 0):

Another encoding using an explicit `empty` and pure expressions

```js
const empty = x =>
  x === empty
  
const sum = ([ x = empty, ...rest ]) =>
  empty (x)
    ? 0
    : x + sum (rest)
    
console.log
  ( sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]) // 15
  , sum ([])                // 0
  )
```

Your other question that asks [how to sum a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031194/633183) was put on-hold for reasons I don't understand. You can adapt the above implementation to support input of nested arrays

```js
const empty = x =>
  x === empty
  
const sum = ([ x = empty, ...rest ]) =>
  empty (x)
    ? 0
    
  : Array.isArray (x)
    ? sum (x) + sum (rest)
  
  : x + sum (rest)
    
console.log
  ( sum ([ 1, [ 2, [ 3, 4 ], 5 ]]) // 15
  , sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])        // 15
  , sum ([[[]]])                   // 0
  , sum ([])                       // 0
  )
```