# Weird loop using recursion in JS function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to sum the elements inside a nested array. For example `arraySum([1,[2,3],5,[[4]]])` should return `15`

Everything seems ok except when I try to `return array.pop() + arraySum(array)` it goes into a weird infinite loop.

Everything goes well until code reaches that code. I tried to return the value of the array and I see no problems at all.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```js
var arraySum = function(array) {
  
  if(array.length === 0){
      return 0
    }
  if(Array.isArray(array[array.length - 1])){
    var x = array[array.length - 1].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);

    array.pop()
    array.push(x)
    return arraySum(array)

    }       

  return  array.pop() + arraySum(array)
};

console.log(arraySum([1,[2,3],5,[[4]]]))
```

Comment: You have `if (array.length = 0)` (which sets `array.length` to 0, deleting everything in the array and evaluating to 0) instead of `if (array.length === 0)`. `a = b` sets `a` to `b`, `a === b` checks if `a` and `b` are equal.

Comment: Hehe sorry I fixed it... but still have the same problem :/

Comment: You sure you saved the changes to the right file? If you make the result visible in the snippet there with `console.log(arraySum([1,[2,3],5,[[4]]]))`, it shows 15 as expected.

Comment: just saw it... weird... in repl.it it returns infinite loop

42
43
44
45
46
47
41
40
38
39
36
37
35
34
33
32
30
31
28
29
48
49
50
51
52
53
54

Native Browser JavaScript
   
InternalError: too much recursion
    at arraySum:36:1
    at arraySum:50:24 .............

Comment: Are you trying it with different input on repl.it?

Comment: I just checked your code in a Repl.it and it worked. Not sure what is your context, but flatten array and summing with reduce is pretty straightfwd, check it out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: What is the problem? When I run the code snippet you posted, it returns `15` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hearty recursion solves our problem here. The issue was that you were mutating the array while iterating over it, specifically pushing items back into it. In practice you should never do this.

```js
    function arraySum(array) {
      if (array.length === 0) {
        return 0;
      }
      return array.reduce((previous, current) => {
        if (Array.isArray(current)) {
          return previous + arraySum(current);
        }
        return previous + current;
      }, 0);
    }

    console.log(arraySum([1, [2, 3], 5, [[4]]]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very educational and informative :)